# boto3 returning more rows than actual rows in timestream

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-timestream

I'm trying to run a query from aws timestream using boto3 in sam from the query I have received 51362 rows whereas when I checked in timestream there were only 1500 rows.

[image: Rows in Timestream]
51362 rows using boto3.

Comment: 1421+ is not a specific figure

Comment: try to count the number row in TimeStream console, you'd find both values identical.